# How to send an array of integer values to an Action using Ajax get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

My action accepts an array of integer values:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int firstParamId, int secondParamId, int[] contactIds)
```

I'm using the below code but the selected array of integers are not sent over.

```
function btnSend_onclick() {

            var firstParamId = 1;
            var secondParamId= 2;
            var selectedContactIds = [];

            $('#ContactsListContainer input:checked').each(function() {
                selectedContactIds.push($(this).val());
            });

            var params = {
                firstParamId : firstParamId ,
                secondParamId: secondParamId,
                contactIds: selectedContactIds
            };

            $.get('/ControllerName/ActionName', JSON.stringify(params))
                .done(function(data, status) {
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(data.responseText);
                });
        }
```

I'm receiving the below error for each parameter:

```
    The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'firstParamId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Actionname(Int32, Int32, Int32[])' 
in 'AppNamespace.MvcUI.Controllers.ControllerName'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
  try this , 

     var param={
      contactIds:[]
     };

        while pushing do param.contactIds.push(...);

       $.get('/ControllerName/ActionName',
        {                   
                "param":  JSON.stringify(param)
        })
        .done(function(data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        })
        .fail(function (data, status) {
                 alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Here a took a global variable in that i created array,then i pushed all the values in that array.Then use JSON.stringify(param) on that while sending.It worked for me.

In Action,

```
String param = (String) request.getParameter("param");
 JSONObject searchCriteriaJSONObj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(param);


 String paramStr = searchCriteriaJSONObj.getString("contactIds");
 List<JSONObject> skillsJSONObj = (List<JSONObject>) JSONArray.fromObject(paramStr);
```

it is in struts2,In struts1 you may need to use plugin for jSOn conversions

Comment: how'd you set the value for contactIds param?

Comment: in action class also you need use JSON conversions

Comment: updated the question to have a better picture. JSON conversions?